# Overriding and return type compatibility

Tags: java, autoboxing, overriding

The following compiles without any problem

```
boolean flag = true;
Boolean flagObj = flag;
```

Now imaging the following scenario

```
interface ITest{

     Boolean getStatus();

}

 class TestImpl implements ITest{

     public boolean getStatus(){ // Compile error: return type is incompatible
         return true;
     }
 }
```

My question is about the compile error at the mentioned line. My Interface mentions return type as `Boolean` but the implemented method returns `boolean`(*the literal*)

My question is, if `Boolean` and `boolean` are compatible then why the compiler is complaining ? Doesn't the autoboxing apply here ?

Comment: Well no, they are not "compatible". One is an object, the other a primitive type. Auto{un,}boxing is one thing, method prototypes are another ;)

Comment: Yes, so the answer is the language is defined like that and this is not a bug in your compiler. Similarly you can't use `int` to override `long`. I mean, it'd be nice to be able to implement a `Void` returning method with a `void` returning one, but you can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only return a sub-class of the parent's return type.

The compile lets you auto-box and unbox between primitives and wrappers but this doesn't make one a sub-class of the other. Primitives are not classes and cannot be used in the way you suggest.

I would just have the getStatus() return `Boolean` or make the parent return `boolean`

In theory, auto-boxing could be extended to allow what you suggest, but I don't imagine much use for it.

In theory you could also write this

```
class A {
    int method() { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    short method() { .... }
}
```

As the compiler supports implicit upcasting.  However again, I suspect there is not much use for this either.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I arrived at this problem inadvertently and that's what I actually thought (_auto-boxing could be extended_) before the compiler flagged the error.

Comment: @Santosh Java tends to be a "feature poor" language and only add things you really need (sometimes very slow to add anything)  On the plus side, most of the feature are well understood with less edge cases (there are still plenty of gotcha's even so)

Answer (score 0):

The methods have different signatures on the prototype and the implementation. The primitive, not being a class, cannot subclass the `Boolean` of the prototype. Even with autoboxing, the implementation violates the general prototype. Auto-unboxing is performed *after* a return so if getStatus was implemented like so:

```
public Boolean getStatus(){ // Compile error: return type is incompatible
     return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

it could be unboxed *after* returning as:

```
if(getStatus()) doSomething();
```

Comment: Ouch, never create a new Boolean or even suggest it.  There is only two possible values and they have been cached since before auto-boxing was added. BTW love the Interrobang.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It was for mainly illustrative effect to emphasize for future readers, but I removed it.

Comment: You could write `Boolean.valueOf(true)` or `Boolean.TRUE`  You would be amazed how many commercial products call `new Boolean` It's a pet hate of mine.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, we can only return a sub-class of the parent's return type.Here Boolean is wrapper class while boolean is primitive data type.In short both are different as wrapper class and primitives.So it gives error of incompatible.