# Type compatibility issues in overriding methods

Tags: java, overriding

I know that a method in `Parent` class, if to be overridden in `Child` class needs to have same name, same arguments and same or a `Subclass` type return type.

But if we have a method with a return type of `long` in `Parent` class and same named (trying to overload) method with same number and same type of arguments but return type `int` then compiler starts complaining, although `int` is convertible to `long` even without a cast.

So why does it only work with class types but not with primitives?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because `int` is not a subtype of `long`.

Comment: but it is compatible so as subclass is compatible with class type and we can assign int to long as subclass type to base class?

Comment: If you are assigning a instance of a subclass to a variable of the baseclass the variable holds an instance of the subclass. But if you assign an int to a long, the int is converted to a long.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the overloaded method's return type has to be the same or a subclass of the parent method's (overwritten method's) return type. **Since `int` is not a subclass of `long`, you can't do that**. Autoboxing allows seemingly automatic conversion between int and long, but one is not a subclass of the other. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548406/overriding-and-return-type-compatibility) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154572/method-return-value-covariance-for-primitives-is-it-works) for more.

Comment: but it is compatible so as subclass is compatible with class type

Comment: Neither one is a subtype of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Because Int is not a subclass of long... When you are trying to assign int to long it won't show any error because of auto boxing concept in java... But auto boxing is not applicable for overriding concepts...

Comment: auto boxing has nothing to do with the question itself.

Comment: Its autoboxing... Java will convert int to long with out explicit casting...

Comment: @KanagarajM please send a link about it

Comment: It's technically a *widening primitive conversion*, not autoboxing. Autoboxing is something entirely different.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html